# request.data.get getting None in patch method

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, request

I am trying to get the id of user but request.get.data is not getting when i tried to print staff_user its showing None.but when use json.loads its working fine but reguest.data.get is showing None.

```
class MyDetailsAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = [MyMultiPartParser]
    serializer_class = Myserializer
    model = Document
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'file_id'

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        staff_user_pk = request.data.get('staff_user_pk')
        if staff_user_pk:
            try:
                staffuser = Staffuser.objects.get(id=staff_user_pk)
            except Staffuser.DoesNotExist as exc:
                raise ValidationError({'detail': exc})

        file = self.get_object()
        file.staffusers.add(staffuser)

        return super().patch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: might be a typo?

Comment: @JPG but json.loads(request.body) seems to be working fine but i need it be request.data.get because it handles some errors

Comment: You have specified `parser_classes` on your view (This is most likely the cause of your problem), without seeing the code for that we can't reproduce your problem. See how to write a [mre]. (Also there seems to be a typo where instead of the closing brace you have a back tick) Also you say `json.loads(request.body)` works, is your request body JSON or form data?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sorry in code it is there while posting the question on stack i missed

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It is json data

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you were correct about the parser_classed when i commented and tried it worked.